# How would one use matrices to find a normal unit vector?

Tags: matrices, 3d, vector-analysis

A recent class assignment involved finding a unit vector perpendicular to a plane, given two unit vectors to start with. The solution given involved using the cross product; I was wondering if such a problem could be solved using a 3x3 matrix (technically, material not yet covered in my class).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can – if you form the determinant of

$$
\pmatrix{u_1&v_1&x_1\\u_2&v_2&x_2\\u_3&v_3&x_3}\;,
$$

where $u$ and $v$ are the two given unit vectors, the coefficients of $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$ form $u\times v$.